# Remove toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, masonry

This is my first time asking a question on here so lets see how it goes! I am using the Masonry grid layout for one of my sites (allworkedup.org), but can not figure out a toggle class issue. Basically, I want only one grid item open at a time, and for that grid item to go away once I click on another. Below is my code. Thanks!!

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true

  });


  $grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
  // change size of item via class
  $( this ).toggleClass('grid-item--gigante');
  // trigger layout
  $grid.masonry();
  //
  });

  $grid.on( 'layoutComplete', function( event, laidOutItems ) {
  console.log( 'Masonry layout complete with ' + laidOutItems.length + '   items' );
  });



// init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```

Comment: Could you include a fiddle to show how this jQuery code is interacting with the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a toggle class feature (which would require a user to click on the item to open and then again to close it), you can use something like:

```
$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
    // Close all other open items and open the one that was just clicked
    $( this ).siblings().removeClass('grid-item--gigante');
    $( this ).addClass('grid-item--gigante');
    // trigger layout
    $grid.masonry();
});
```

This way, when a user clicks on one of the grid items, all the siblings of that item (so all the other boxes) are closed, and the one that was clicked will expand instead.